# Is s3.buckets.all() updates during run time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():               
        print(bucket.name)
```

In this code `s3.buckets.all()` will have same number of elements till loop completes or it will update iteratively.

Comment: the s3.buckets.all() is going to be called once and then python is going to iterate over the resulting collection.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As @MokonaModoki mentioned, the response of s3.buckets.all() will not be changed during iteration.